# chaining ajax functions - where to place async await

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, async-await

here is the scenario:

`btnplus` function - inserts some new data into a database

it calls `get_atitles` - which is also an ajax call to populate a div with the new set of data

when the div is populated - `go_find` should find a specific element inside the new set. This is not an ajax

problem - `go_find` starts before `get_atitles` is finished so it cannot find the required data

I tried to place `async await` on various places - without success

so how to call `go_find` after `get_atitles` is completed ?

```
$(btnplus).on('click', function(){
    ...
    $.post('pro.php', {fn: 'btn_plus_fi', args: [path]}, async function(data){
        // some new data is added to database
        await get_atitles(); // load the new set of data into a div
        go_find(str); // find a specific data inside a new set
    });
});

function get_atitles(){
    ...
    $.post('pro.php', {fn: 'get_atitles', args: [par]}, function(data){
        atitles.html(data);
    });
}

function go_find(str){
    // find something inside `atitles`
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: so how to call go_find after get_atitles is completed ?

Just put `go_find` function call inside the `get_atitles` result handler.

```
$(btnplus).on('click', function() {

  $.post('pro.php', {
    fn: 'btn_plus_fi',
    args: [path]
  }, async function(data) {
    // some new data is added to database
    await get_atitles(); // load the new set of data into a div
  });
});

function get_atitles() {

  $.post('pro.php', {
    fn: 'get_atitles',
    args: [par]
  }, function(data) {

    atitles.html(data);

    go_find(str); // find a specific data inside a new set
  });
}

function go_find(str) {
  // find something inside `atitles`
}
```

Alternative

```
$(btnplus).on('click', function () {

  $.post('pro.php', { fn: 'btn_plus_fi', args: [path] }, async function (data) {
    // some new data is added to database
    $.post('pro.php', { fn: 'get_atitles', args: [par] }, function (data) {
      atitles.html(data);
      go_find(str); // find a specific data inside a new set
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I see but in that case I need to send the variable `str` to `get_atitles` and because I use that function somewhere else (wihout arguments) - I need then an extra `if else var is set...` - things become complicated. The ideal solution would be to call both functions (`get_atitles` and `go_find`) from `btnclick` function, but sequentially - one after another

Comment: Alternative added

Comment: in that case - it will work - although I would rather keep the rule - one function for one thing. i.e. - `btn click` for inserting new data - and `get-atitles` for getting them. Have you any idea - why my try with `async await` - doesn't work ?